# How to LEFT JOIN while using a filter on the LEFT table?

Tags: mysql, join, filter

I have 2 tables that I want to LEFT JOIN and filter the results on the LEFT table.
The tables are:
   -product_table, with columns id and product_name
   -order_table, with columns id, product_id, product_order

I tried to select a row from the product table where the id was 1 and LEFT JOIN the order table where the product id was the same as the id in the product table.

My first try was like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_table 
WHERE product_table.id = 1
LEFT JOIN order_table
ON order_table.product_id=product_table.id
```

For this query I got a syntax error.

So I searched how I could LEFT JOIN and filter the results from the LEFT table and I found to use the AND after LEFT JOIN in the query, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM product_table
LEFT JOIN order_table
ON order_table.product_id=product_table.id
AND product_table.id=1
```

But here the query returns all the product_table rows and all the corresponding order_table rows, all joined, but all I want is just the product_table row where the id equals 1 and to be joined with the corresponding order_table row.
How can I do this?

Comment: your query looks fine. Can you show a small data sample for products and orders?

Comment: Don't use [`SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/) unless you're writing a DB administration program; select only the columns you need.

Comment: your first query is right use where clause after the  join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM product_table pt 
    LEFT JOIN order_table ot 
      ON ot.product_id=pt.id
  WHERE pt.id = 1
```

Comment: can you explain please? i cant understand what the pt and ot are there for.

Comment: Sorry they are just Alias's for the tables so I didn't have to type the full table names the following should also work SELECT * FROM product_table
LEFT JOIN order_table ON order_table.product_id=product_table.id
WHERE product_table.id = 1

Comment: +1: the first query of the OP would be correct if the where clause came after the join.

Comment: pt and ot are the alias of the tables, used in the query the aliasing is very useful to reduce the complexity of the table names.

Answer (score 1):

You should to re write your query like this :=

```
SELECT * FROM product_table
LEFT JOIN order_table
ON order_table.product_id=product_table.id
AND product_table.id=1
where product_table.id=1
```

If you not use where clause then the all records are fetched from your product_table with matching condition placed in on clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the syntax for [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html), you'll see that the `WHERE` clause must come after the `JOIN` clause.